# Why 'flask-RESTful' not found in 'vent/bin'?

Tags: python, flask-restful

When installing `flask` and `flask-RESTful`:

```
% pip install flask-RESTful
```

Why the `flask-RESTful` package does not seem to be located in `venv/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally all pip installations will be located in something along the lines of:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/x.x/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/your-package`

You can specify where to install the package by using:

`pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default package_name`